# Nominal types bound to a specific function

Tags: haskell, types, f#, domain-driven-design

Is there a language or type system that supports defining types that can only be instantiated via a specific function.

An example could be a type `NonZeroInteger` that is bound to the function `CreateNonZeroInteger`.  Any external code can access the type, receive and return values of this type.  But crucially, a value of that type can only be created by calling the function `CreateNonZeroInteger`

`NonZeroInteger`should be nominally typed.  A value of another type with the same structure should not be comparable or castable to this type.

Comment: I think this is normally done with a module which hides the data constructor and exposes a function which wraps the data constructor. See the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531032/using-types-to-force-correctness

Comment: In f# you could use access modifiers but it would be ugly

Comment: "*Is there a language or type system that supports defining types that can only be instantiated via a specific function.*" Well, C++ for one; but I don't know of any _Hindley–Milner-based_ type system that supports it outright, which seems to be what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a type, define a function to create values of that type, then export the type and your function but *not* the type’s data constructor. For example, in Haskell, given your example:

```hs
module My.Module.NonZeroInteger (NonZeroInteger, createNonZeroInteger) where

newtype NonZeroInteger = NonZeroInteger Integer
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

createNonZeroInteger :: Integer -> Maybe NonZeroInteger
createNonZeroInteger 0 = Nothing
createNonZeroInteger x = Just $ NonZeroInteger x
```

Consumers of `My.Module.NonZeroInteger` will be able to create values of type `NonZeroInteger`, but since the data constructor is not exported, they won’t ever be able to create `NonZeroInteger`s that are internally `0`.

The custom constructor function, in this case `createNonZeroInteger`, is traditionally called a [“smart constructor”](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors).

Comment: I was really hoping for the type itself to be bound to the function in the signature instead of taking advantage of module encapsulation.  But this is really helpful and answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth putting on record here that you can do exactly the same thing as Alexis King suggests in F# by making the union case constructors `private`.

```
type NonZeroInteger = private NonZeroInteger of int

let tryCreateNonZeroInteger = function
    |0 -> None
    |x -> Some <| NonZeroInteger x
```

The type itself remains publically accessible but it can only be created and decomposed via functions you supply.