# Functions that only work with one constructor of a type

Tags: haskell, types, message-queue, data-kinds

I'm writing a lib for message queues. Queues can be either `Direct` or `Topic`. `Direct` queues have a static binding key, while `Topic` queues can have dynamic ones.

I want to write a function `publish` that only works on `Direct` queues. This works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

type Name = Text
type DirectKey = Text
type TopicKey = [Text]

data QueueType
  = Direct DirectKey
  | Topic TopicKey

data Queue (kind :: a -> QueueType)
  = Queue Name QueueType
```

This requires two separate constructors

```
directQueue :: Name -> DirectKey -> Queue 'Direct

topicQueue :: Name -> TopicKey -> Queue 'Topic
```

But when I go to write publish, there's an extra pattern that I need to match which should be impossible

```
publish :: Queue 'Direct -> IO ()
publish (Queue name (Direct key)) =
   doSomething name key
publish _ =
   error "should be impossible to get here"
```

Is there a better way to model this problem so that I don't need that pattern match? `Direct` queues should always have that `Text` metadata, and `Topic` queues should always have that `[Text]` metadata. Is there a better way to enforce this at both the type and value level?

Comment: Is there a reason you need a parameterized `Queue` type, instead of two distinct types `newtype DirectQueue = DQ Text` and `newtype TopicQueue = TQ [Text]`?

Comment: @chepner - They have a lot in common with each other. I took out the extra info to simplify the problem. I'll add it back in to the example to demonstrate.

Comment: I added back in a `Name` for the queues to show that they have information in common. In my real application, there are several functions that should work with any queue, and a Queue has two non-distinct fields in addition to queue type.

Comment: Have a read of this, it is similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531032/using-types-to-force-correctness

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about making `Queue` a plain polymorphic type

```
data Queue a = Queue Name a
```

And then defining separate `Queue DirectKey` and `Queue TopicKey` types? Then you wouldn't need to pattern-match in `publish :: Queue DirectKey -> IO ()`.

If, apart from that, you need functions that should work in any `Queue`, perhaps you could define some common operations in a typeclass of which `DirectKey` and `TopicKey` would be instances, and then have signatures like

```
commonFunction :: MyTypeclass a => Queue a -> IO ()
```

Maybe you could put such functions directly in the typeclass

```
class MyTypeclass a where
    commonFunction :: Queue a -> IO ()
```

Comment: This is great. I was definitely overthinking it. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good talk on how adding a type parameter to another type can be useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHjIl81HgfE

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't compile as-is (it requires `PolyKinds` to be turned on as well) so I don't know if it's only an accident, but it looks like you were trying to go for the approach where you know from the type of a queue which constructors could be involved, and so can statically guarantee that a function can only be called on a certain kind of queue.

You can in fact get that approach to work, using multiple constructors of a GADT (as opposed to using multiple completely separate types, with a type class to bring them together when necessary, in teh approach suggested in @danidiaz' answer).

But first why your current code doesn't work. In your queue type:

```
data Queue (kind :: a -> QueueType)
  = Queue Name QueueType
```

you're parameterising the `Queue` type by a type variable (called `kind`), allowing you to tag a `Queue` at the type level by what kind of `QueueType` you want to be in it. But only constructor `Queue Name QueueType` makes no reference to `kind` at all; it's a phantom type. That `QueueType` slot can be filled by any valid queue type regardless of what `kind` is in the `Queue kind` type of the queue.

This means that GHC was correct in wanting you to add a case to `publish` that would match a topic key inside a `Queue 'Direct`; your data type definition says that such values can exist.

What GADTs allow you to do is to explicitly declare the full type of each constructor separately, *including the return type*. So you can set up a relation between the type of the value you're constructing and the constructors (or their parameters) that could possibly be used to make a value of that type.

In concrete terms, we can make a type for your queues such that `Queue 'Direct` can *only* contain a direct queue type, and `Queue 'Topic` can *only* contain a topic queue type, and you can handle either by polymorphically accepting a `Queue a`.

It's simplest to make `QueueType` *just* be used for the tag, and have a separate GADT storing the data. In your original code you were able to reuse the data-holding constructors lifted to the type level and unapplied, but that makes your kind signatures unnecessarily complicated (bringing in the need for `PolyKinds`), and if you need to add more (and different numbers of!) parameters to the data constructors it will become increasingly difficult to shoehorn their unapplied types to fit the same kind when lifted to type level. So:

```
data QueueType
  = Direct
  | Topic

data QueueData (a :: QueueType)
  where DirectData :: DirectKey -> QueueData 'Direct
        TopicData :: TopicKey -> QueueData 'Topic
```

So we've got `QueueType` just to lift with `DataKinds` (there's often no need to ever actually use such a type at the value level). Then we've got the type `QueueData` parametersised by a type-level `QueueType`. One constructor takes a `DirectKey` and constructs a `QueueData 'Direct`, the other takes a `TopicKey` and constructs a `QueueData 'Topic`.

Then it's simple to have a `Queue` type that similarly is tagged with 
the type of queue being represented:

```
data Queue (a :: QueueType)
  = Queue Name (QueueData a)
```

Now if a function works on any queue (say because it only needs access to the name outside of the `QueueData`), it can take a `Queue a`:

```
getName :: Queue a -> Text
getName (Queue name _) = name
```

You can also take a `Queue a` if you can explicitly handle all cases, and you'll get warnings when you miss a case:

```
getKeyText :: Queue a -> Text
getKeyText (Queue _ (DirectData key)) = key
getKeyText (Queue _ (TopicData keys)) = mconcat keys
```

And finally, when taking a `Queue 'Direct` as in your `publish` function, GHC knows that `DirectData` is the only possible constructor for the `QueueData`. So you don't need to add an error case as in the OP, and it would in fact be detected as a type error if you tried to handle a `TopicData` inside there.

Full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Text (Text)

type Name = Text
type DirectKey = Text
type TopicKey = [Text]

data QueueType
  = Direct
  | Topic

data QueueData (a :: QueueType)
  where DirectData :: DirectKey -> QueueData 'Direct
        TopicData :: TopicKey -> QueueData 'Topic

data Queue (a :: QueueType)
  = Queue Name (QueueData a)


getName :: Queue a -> Text
getName (Queue name _) = name

getKeyText :: Queue a -> Text
getKeyText (Queue _ (DirectData key)) = key
getKeyText (Queue _ (TopicData keys)) = mconcat keys

publish :: Queue 'Direct -> IO ()
publish (Queue name (DirectData key))
  = doSomething name key
  where doSomething = undefined
```

Comment: I think `PolyKinds` is rather more than necessary. `KindSignatures` should be sufficient.

Comment: @dfeuer The OP's code as written has a kind variable `a` in the kind of `kind :: a -> QueueType`. My system (ghc 8.0.1) certainly won't accept it with `KindSignatures` and no `PolyKinds`.